# Why can't I catch an import error in React Native?

Tags: react-native, commonjs, sjcl

This code fails in React Native, but not in Node:

```
try {
  return require('module-does-not-exist');
}catch (e) {
  return null;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why?

#### Why I care:

I am trying to use the [Stanford JavaScript Crypto Library](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/tree/version-0.8) in my React Native app, and it's failing on import because it uses this pattern to optionally use the node `crypto` builtin. ([source code](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/00bd42dae9ebc3a28708db2053ffa2e88f99ad1e/core/random.js#L484-L489))

It appears others have hit this snag before: https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom/pull/44